# how to expand the dynamically created UIviews on clicking of the UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have created dynamic `UIView` with `scrollview` and `UIView` is having subview `UIbutton`.
my requirement is on clicking of the `UIButton` I need to show one more `UIView` in between the dynamic `UIviews`.
I need to know how to change the dynamic `UIView` frame size dynamically on clicking of the `UIbutton`.

Thanks in advance.
here is the samples

```
    NSArray *subViews = [createIssueScroll subviews];
    NSLog(@"%@",subViews);
    NSInteger tag=[sender tag];
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    UIView *vw = [createIssueScroll viewWithTag:tag];
    [self createIssueSubView:[vw frame]];

    UIView *sVW = [createIssueScroll viewWithTag:(tag+1)];
     NSLog(@"%@", sVW);


    float y;
    y = sVW.frame.origin.y;
    sVW.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, sVW.frame.size.width, sVW.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f", y);
```

code explanation

i have created button through programatically, i will explain in detail above code

In first line i have taken all the scrollview subviews(dynamically created UiViews)
i have button tag value
and add a method of UIsubviews(this subview is displaying on clicking of ui button)
suppose i have click dynamically created first Uiview button, need to show subview after the first dynamic UIview and second dynamic UIview is push to down side.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with exactly? You can change the size of a view by setting the frame like you have in your code above. And how have you added the button to the view - in code or in interface builder/storyboard?

Comment: i have created button through programatically, i will explain in detail above code 
NSArray *subViews = [createIssueScroll subviews];
    NSLog(@"%@",subViews);
    NSInteger tag=[sender tag];
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    UIView *vw = [createIssueScroll viewWithTag:tag];
    [self createIssueSubView:[vw frame]];

    UIView *sVW = [createIssueScroll viewWithTag:(tag+1)];
     NSLog(@"%@", sVW);


    float y;
    y = sVW.frame.origin.y;
    sVW.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, sVW.frame.size.width, sVW.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f", y);

Comment: i don't see a button in that code(?)

Comment: -(void)createIssueBtn:(id)sender
{
    
    NSArray *subViews = [createIssueScroll subviews];
    NSLog(@"%@",subViews);
    NSInteger tag=[sender tag];
    NSLog(@"%d", tag);
    UIView *vw = [createIssueScroll viewWithTag:tag];
    [self createIssueSubView:[vw frame]];
    
    UIView *sVW = [createIssueScroll viewWithTag:(tag+1)];
     NSLog(@"%@", sVW);
    
    
    float y;
    y = sVW.frame.origin.y;
    sVW.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, sVW.frame.size.width, sVW.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f", y);
    
}

Answer (score 0):

Find `subViews` by using `foreach`

```
UIView *firstView;
UIView *seconfView;

for(id currentview in scrollView.subviews)
{
    if([currentview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
    {
        UIView *view = (UIView *)currentview;

        if(view.tag == 1) //1 is your view tag
        {
            firstView = view;
        }
        if(view.tag == 2) //2 is your view tag
        {
            seconfView = view;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use first and second views :)

Comment: yea i have taken all the dynamically created UIviews tag.
and now i want to add the one more UISubview in between the dynamically created UIviews.

i mean on clicking of the first uiview button need to display subview and remaining views need to be moving down side.

Comment: first and second view are your views you can get their frame and whatever you want to do.

Comment: on clicking of the first view button i need to add one more subview below the first view(expand/collapse) and remaining views are moving down side.

Comment: then add new button below the clicked one and increase y co-ordinates of all below views.